# Entity Framework Core foreign key from separate database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, relational-database, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am new to EF Core and databases in general since I am a student still. I have a requirement in the project I am making to have a separate Identity database from the application database.

I have the identity database setup already using the ASP.NET Core Identity with some custom properties. I am putting together another database to store tickets for a contact page and for some reason I can't seem to get the foreign keys to work properly. When I migrate the new database it creates a duplicate table in my Application database for the Identity class that I've already customized in the Identity database.

I was wondering how to prevent this and if its related to the foreign key since information that I am finding online seems to indicate this isn't supported by EF Core 2.1

**Identity** class in models:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebTemplate.Models
{
    public class Identity : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string Room { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ContactForm** class in models:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebTemplate.Models
{
    public enum StatusCode
    {
        [Display(Name="Open")]Open,
        [Display(Name = "Under Review")] UnderReview,
        [Display(Name = "Pending Change")] PendingChange,
        [Display(Name = "Closed-Resolved")] Resolved,
        [Display(Name = "Closed-No Action")] NoAction
    }

    public class ContactForm
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContactFormId { get; set; }
        public string SenderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
        public Identity Sender { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public StatusCode Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AppIdentityDbContext**:

```
//removed for brevity
namespace WebTemplate.Models
{
    public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Identity>
    {
        public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        //Seed Data removed for brevity
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**:

```
//removed for brevity
namespace WebTemplate.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<ContactForm> ContactForms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Foreign keys cannot span across databases. You can only apply them to tables in the same database.